# Issues with Serializer in Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I wanted to create serializer for my model who have nested relationship.My models looks like this :

```
class Master(models.Model):
    en = models.TextField('English')

class Album(models.Model):
    pk_album = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=True)
    title = models.OneToOneField(Master, related_name='Album_title')
    description = models.OneToOneField(Master, related_name='Album_description')


class Track(models.Model):
    pk_track = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk_album_parent = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='track_parent')
    fk_album_child = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='track_child')
```

**And My serializer :**

```
class masterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Master
        fields = ('en',)

class albumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_title = masterSerializer()
    album_description = masterSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_title', 'album_description')

class trackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    track_parent = albumSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    track_child = albumSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('track_parent', 'track_child')
```

And I am using this `trackSerializer` in my views . but when in browser I am getting nothing means no fields or data just blank json .

I am confused how to handle this nested relationships in serlaizer so that my end API works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You defined your `trackSerializer` in wrong way.

`Track` model doesn't have `track_parent` or `track_child` attributes. They belong to `Album`  model. Remember that `related_name` is an attribute to defined how your pointed model, in this case `Album` may retrieve their backwards model instances aka `Track` instances. `related_name` does not rename the attribute as you think it does.

Also, `track_parent` represents `Track` instances, you can't serializer a `Track` instance using `albumSerializer`

```
class trackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('pk_track',)


class albumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    album_title = masterSerializer()
    album_description = masterSerializer()
    track_parent = trackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    track_child = trackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_title', 'album_description','track_parent', 'track_child')
```

Comment: Here   `track_parent = albumSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`  will  `albumSerializer` can able to call himself ?? Doesn't it give not defined error ?

Comment: @n.imp yes sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: But it is giving not defined error ,  
  `Adjacency_parent = albumSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
NameError: name 'albumSerializer' is not defined`

Comment: @n.imp I fixed it, check my answer, it should be trackSerializer not albumSerializer

Comment: Yes it works , last question. API response must have included all  `fields (album_title, album_description etc)`  but my response only includes  `pk_track`  as it is the only field mentioned in `trackSerializer`

Comment: @n.imp because you are retrieving Track Serializer data, not Album and you only defined pk_track  in your Track Serializer.

Comment: @n.imp If this answer was helpful to you, you can check it as correct answer by clicking over check mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72903/discussion-between-n-imp-and-levi).